# Printing a scoreboard with a sliding arrow C++ beginner

Tags: c++, printing, menu

I am working on a program to code a game called **Devil's Dice**.  I have the logic of code working perfectly, but I am struggling to print the scoreboard to show the games progress.  The details of the assignment are below, followed by my code.  I don't know where to begin printing the scoreboard as shown in the image I linked.

In our version of Devil's Dice the rules will be as follows:

The player repeatedly rolls a 6-sided die until either a 1 is rolled or the player decides to "hold".

- If the player rolls a 1, they lose any points accumulated this turn and the devil gets a turn.
- If the player rolls any other number, it is added to their turn total and the player's turn continues.
- If a player chooses to "hold", their current turn total is added to their score and the devil gets a turn.

**Devil's Logic**

If the score is tied or the devil is winning, he will keep rolling until he has at least 21 points (unless he has already reached 100 points)
If the player is winning, the devil will keep rolling until he has at least 30 points (unless he has already reached 100 points)
If the devil rolls a 1, he also loses the points he has accumulated on his turn
If the player chooses to "forfeit", they lose and the game is over.
The player must score 100 points before the devil manages to do so in order to win.

For example, the player, Ann, begins a turn with a roll of 5. Ann could hold and score 5 points, but chooses to roll again. Ann rolls a 2, and could hold with a turn total of 7 points, but chooses to roll again. Ann rolls a 1, and must end her turn without scoring. The devil then rolls the sequence 4-5-3-5-5, chooses to hold, and adds his turn total of 22 points to his score.

There are a few other details about the game logic but i am confident i have it working correctly.  I am just wondering how to get a menu with a moving arrow as shown below.

[image: the scoreboard should look like this]

[image: This is an example game]

My code looks like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() { //just for a school grading program//
#ifdef JARVIS
    srand(0);
#else
    srand(time(NULL));
#endif
// Call your functions to play your game here...

    char userInput;
    int diceRoll;
    int turnScore = 0;
    int totalScore = 0;
    int devilScore = 0;
    bool isItDevilsTurn = false;
    bool winner = false;
    int devilWins = 0;
    int playerWins = 0;

    cout << "---- Welcome to Devil's Dice! ----" << endl;
    cout << "Hold[h], roll[r], or forfeit[f]: " << endl;

    while (!winner) {
        if (!isItDevilsTurn) {
            cin >> userInput;

            if (userInput == 'h')
            {
                totalScore = totalScore + turnScore;
                cout << "You banked " << turnScore << " points and have a total of " << totalScore << " points" << endl;
                isItDevilsTurn = true;
                turnScore = 0;
            }

            if (userInput == 'r')
            {
                diceRoll = rand() % 6 + 1;

                if (diceRoll > 1)
                {
                    cout << "You rolled a " << diceRoll << "!" << endl;
                    turnScore = turnScore + diceRoll;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "You rolled a 1 :(" << endl;
                    turnScore = 0;
                    isItDevilsTurn = true;

                }
            }

            if (totalScore >= 100) {
                winner = true;
                cout << "You Win!" << endl;
                playerWins = playerWins + 1;
            }

            if (userInput == 'f') {
                cout << "Game Over!" << endl;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            int devilGoal = 21;

            if (totalScore > devilScore)
            {
                devilGoal = 30;
            }

            while (isItDevilsTurn)
            {
                diceRoll = rand() % 6 + 1;
                if (diceRoll > 1 && turnScore < devilGoal)
                {
                    cout << "devil rolled " << diceRoll << endl;
                    turnScore = turnScore + diceRoll;

                }
                else if (diceRoll > 1 && turnScore > devilGoal)
                {
                    devilScore = devilScore + turnScore;
                    cout << "devil holds " << turnScore << " points and now has " << devilScore << " points" << endl;
                    isItDevilsTurn = false;
                    turnScore = 0;

                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "devil rolled a 1" << endl;
                    isItDevilsTurn = false;
                    turnScore = 0;
                }

                if (devilScore >= 100)
                {
                    cout << "Devil Wins!" << endl;
                    devilWins = devilWins + 1;
                    winner = true;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Total Wins: " << playerWins << endl;
    cout << "Total Losses: " << devilWins << endl;

    fstream output("games.txt");
    output << playerWins << " " << devilWins << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What's your actual question? Please be precise. You don't seem to be printing any part of the scoreboard yet.

Comment: i do not know how to print a scoreboard that looks like that.  And i do not know how to move the 'pointer' once i do.  Sorry for the confusion

Comment: My question is simply, how to use my existing code to print a scoreboard that matches the one shown with the --> moving to match the user and devil's score.

Comment: Your existing code doesn't print a scoreboard, you will need to write new code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I'm not too good with tabs, so you just make it looks like you need to. I used a ternary operator to understand if I need to write number or a tab in cuurent line

```
printf("\tPlayer\t\t\tDevil\n");
printf("\t------\t\t\t-----\n");
for(int i = 10; i >= 0; --i){
      printf((totalScore < (i+1)*10 && totalScore >=i*10) ? "%d >" : "\t", totalScore);
      printf("--%d", i*10);
      printf((turnScore < (i+1)*10 && turnScore >=i*10) ? "< %d" : "\t\t\t", turnScore);
      printf((devilTotal < (i+1)*10 && devilTotal >=i*10) ? "%d >" : "\t", devilTotal);
      printf("--%d", i*10);
      printf((devilTurn < (i+1)*10 && devilTurn >=i*10) ? "< %d" : "\t\t", devilTurn);
      printf("\n");
}
```

How it works? first `printf()` I evaluate `totalScore`, if it's less then next value and more than current I print it, otherwise just print tab. Second `printf()` prints current value. Third `printf()` evalutes `turnScore`, if it's less then next value and more than current I print it, otherwise just print 2 tabs.

Same for devil.

It would be the same with `cin` and `cout`, it's just that I feel more confident with `printf()`. If it looks right, all you need to do is work with alignments.